# Como saber si un String contiene alguna de las 10 primeras letras del abecedario VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, string

Tengo que hacer un programa en vb.net para sacar si un `string` que se ingresa por teclado contiene alguna de las 10 primeras letras del abecedario o no.
He probado con esto pero no ha dado resultado

```
    Overloads Sub MostrarDatosCalculados(ByVal nombre As String, ByVal municipio As String)
    Dim Resultado As Boolean = nombre Like "[A-J]"
    Dim Resultado2 As Boolean = municipio Like "[A-J]"
    If Resultado = True Then
        Console.WriteLine("El nombre contiene una de las diez primeras letras del abecedario.")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("El nombre NO contiene una de las diez primeras letras del abecedario")
    End If
    If Resultado2 = True Then
        Console.WriteLine("El municipio contiene una de las diez primeras letras del abecedario.")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("El municipio NO contiene una de las diez primeras letras del abecedario")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Que contenga todas o que contenga alguna de ellas? El título de la pregunta dice una cosa, pero los mensajes de tu código dicen otra

Comment: @PabloLozano tiene razón, tu pregunta no coincide con el texto que muestras en tu código.

Comment: Solo es necesario que contenga una de las letras

Comment: Hola Josu. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para modificar  y añadir ejemplos de palabras/frases validas e invalidas. un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Editado**

Tras tu aclaración, parece que lo que quieres es saber si la cadena contiene alguno de los 10 primeros caracteres. Solución con LINQ:

```
Dim letras As Char() = Enumerable.Range(Convert.ToInt32("a"c), Convert.ToInt32("j"c) - Convert.ToInt32("a"c) + 1).[Select](Function(c) Chr(c)).ToArray()
Dim algunaLetra = nombre.ToLower().Any(Function(x) letras.Contains(x))
```

Creamos un `Char()` con los caracteres de la `a` a la `j`, y luego comprobamos si existe algun caso en el que `letras` contenga alguna letra de la cadena de entrada

Dejo mi antigua solución ya que puede ser interesante:

---

Para comprobar si una cadena contiene al menos una vez las 10 primeras letras del abecedario:

```
Dim todasLasLetras = nombre.ToLower().Where(Function(x) x >= "a"c AndAlso x <= "j"c).Distinct().Count() = 10
```

Básicamente, convertimos el nombre a minúsculas, obtenemos todas las letras comprendidas entre la `a` y la `j` que sean distintas, y si son exactamente 10, tenemos que la cadena tiene todas las letras.